# How to fix executing long process using python in php

Tags: php, python

I am trying to run a python script that acts like a make file using PHP, the problem is the python script will take up to 1 minute to finalize and at the end it will output (Complete). The when i run it using php it takes few seconds and outputs the complete string from the python script. something is breaking the process and i don't know what.

```
            $default = ini_get('max_execution_time');
            set_time_limit(0);
            ini_set('max_execution_time',2*60);
            ignore_user_abort();
            echo shell_exec('python3 make.py /var/www/html/files'); 
            set_time_limit($default);
```

Expected result must be Completed after the long process.

Actual result: few seconds and i get Completed.

Python script works fine fully tested.

Comment: Wait so you're getting the "Complete" message after a few seconds? In which case your error is probably in the Python script, because PHP is behaving as expected, no?

Comment: Hi, the python script works perfectly, if i run it it will take about a minute and after that the message Complete, but when i run it with php i think is skipping or killing the long process and is printing Complete

Comment: Two things come to mind, when running `shell_exec`, you're running the py script from a different (folder) location than what you may be running your script normally from. Is your script folder/location agnostic? Also, when running shell_exec, you will be running the py script using a different _user_, so it could be that this other user doesn't have the requisite permissions, thus the py script concludes prematurely.